# SSH apparently not reading keys inside ~/.ssh

Tags: ssh

This is output from a Ubuntu 16.04 client:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/manuth/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/manuth/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for r2d2.manuth.life
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to r2d2.manuth.life [103.12.163.90] port 900.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/manuth/.ssh/dqar-rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/manuth/.ssh/dqar-rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

The path and permission for `/home/manuth/.ssh/dqar-rsa` are also correct:

```
$ ls -l /home/manuth/.ssh/dqar-rsa*
-rw------- 1 manuth manuth 3243 Nov  7 11:27 /home/manuth/.ssh/dqar-rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 manuth manuth  740 Nov  7 11:27 /home/manuth/.ssh/dqar-rsa.pub
```

The entry for this host in `~/.ssh/config` is:

```
host r2d2.manuth.life
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/dqar-rsa
 Port 900
 IdentitiesOnly yes
 ForwardX11 yes
```

If I try commenting the `IdentityFile` line, it doesn't even read any `id_*` inside `~/.ssh`:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/manuth/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to r2d2.manuth.life [103.12.163.90] port 900.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/manuth/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/manuth/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/manuth/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/manuth/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/manuth/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/manuth/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/manuth/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 4
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/manuth/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

This seems to come up all of a sudden today.

Edit: contents inside `~/.ssh`:

```
$ ls -la
insgesamt 36
drwx------  2 manuth manuth 4096 Nov  7 16:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 53 manuth manuth 4096 Nov  7 13:31 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 manuth manuth  805 Nov  7 12:10 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r--  1 manuth manuth  543 Nov  7 13:47 config
-rw-------  1 manuth manuth  411 Nov  7 12:10 dqar-ed25519
-rw-r--r--  1 manuth manuth   96 Nov  7 12:10 dqar-ed25519.pub
-rw-------  1 manuth manuth 3243 Nov  7 12:10 dqar-rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 manuth manuth  740 Nov  7 12:10 dqar-rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 manuth manuth 1990 Nov  7 15:14 known_hosts
```

Edit 2: Ah hah, the console output was several lines of this:

```
Nov 7 13:51:32 dqar sshd [11316]: fatal: Missing privilege separation directory: /var/empty
```

The server in question is FreeBSD 10.3.

Comment: Can you please perform a `ls -la` on the .ssh directory and add the output to your question.

Comment: Check the SSH log on the other side, on the server you're trying to connect to. Likely there is a permission problem there, the logs will tell you where.

Comment: @BrettLevene see my edit in the OP.

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you please check the permissions on the remote servers' relevant home directory too? Ensure that there's no write permission bit set on either the group or other.

Comment: Just found the cause and solution: I had no `/var/empty`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
debug1: identity file /home/manuth/.ssh/dqar-rsa type 1
```

Says it read the file successfully. The failure is somewhere else.

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

This is the real problem. You can't establish SSH connection to the remote host for some reason. You are probably blacklisted using `/etc/hosts.deny` or the server is failing to accept the connections and initiate SSH protocol for other reasons (missing directories, disk failures, full disk, etc.). The logs from the server will tell you more.

```
Nov 7 13:51:32 dqar sshd [11316]: fatal: Missing privilege separation directory: /var/empty
```

Explains it pretty much. You need to create this directory if it was removed for some reasons and set proper permissions (not writable by any other users than root).

Comment: I don't think I'm blacklisted however; still the same output even when I connect to it through VPN (and use the local IP address instead).

Comment: So check the server log as advised above. Or something else is breaking your connection. But it is not certainly related to any of your client keys.

Comment: Overall a good answer. Though the part about *probably blacklisted using /etc/hosts.deny* seems like jumping to conclusions. There are lots of other possible reasons for the connection being broken at that point. I think last time I saw that happen it was caused by a disk failure on the server.

Comment: Apparently I don't have /var/empty. See my edit in the OP.

Comment: @kasperd yes, there are more possibilities. I added to the answer what was missing. Thanks for addition.

Comment: _"You can't establish connection to the remote host for some reason."_ - That is incorrect; the connection has been established, and is _then_ closed by the other side. That's an important distinction because the causes for the two situations are quite different.

Comment: @marcelm It depends on the level you are describing the "connection". When you talk about TCP connection, you are right, when you talk about SSH connection it is not the case. But I understand it can be better worded.

Comment: fwiw I got this error when connecting to my mac remotely, I think the ssh server was running out of file handles, a reboot of the mac fixed it

Answer (score 5):

So the reason was that, somehow, there was no `/var/empty`. I created it back from this forum post (I know it's for Juniper, but it's working on this FreeBSD as well):
http://forums.juniper.net/t5/Ethernet-Switching/Missing-privilege-separation-directory-var-empty/td-p/173832

Comment: Good for you for posting the actual answer, but I think you owe it to Jakuje to accept his/her answer: it was his/her analysis that nothing was wrong client-side that led you to the server, and to my mind (s)he deserves the credit.

Comment: @MadHatter I did upvoted him/her though.