# ssh connection : ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, mac-osx

i'm kind of a newbie for all of this but i'll try to explain my best.
First of all i'm on MacOSX
I have a remote server under ubuntu to which i would like to access by ssh.

The system administrator gave me an IPsec, when i'm connected to it, i don't have access to the internet, but i can connect by ssh to my server.
So wherever i am i can connect to the VPN IPsec and then to my remote server without having to be on the local network.

Now i also have access from my desk to a local internet connection, from there i can ping the server and i can also access to it through a web interface (by typing the ip address in my browser) BUT i cannot connect to the server with ssh.

here is what i get:

```
$ ssh XX.XXX.XXX.X -v
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/me/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/me/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to XX.XXX.XXX.X port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out
```

before getting that i tried to generate rsa key and to put my public key on the remote server (since i can connect with the VPN) but i still get error.
As you can see the connection is established though it looks like something is preventing the communication between my computer and the server
and until now i haven't found any solution to this problem...

**edit 1 :**
so i tried with extra verbose -vvv, but i don't see any difference

```
$ ssh XX.XXX.XXX.X -vvv
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/me/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/me/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to XX.XXX.XXX.X port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out
```

**edit 2 :**
so i try to add a bit more information: i generated a rsa key, and i copy/paste my public key on the remote server in .ssh/authorized_keys

when i check the log on the server this way :

```
cat /var/log/auth.log
```

there is no trace on my connection attempt

Comment: Run your ssh connection attempt with -vvv to get fully verbose output from the attempt.

Check for any networking issue between your location and your droplet by running a ping and traceroute (or MTR) to check for packet loss or extremely high latency.

Comment: Are you sure you have both a public and private key under your .ssh directory in your home? Are you able to connect to the server locally on the remote location?¨Perhaps this post could be usefull https://serverfault.com/questions/813519/ssh-apparently-not-reading-keys-inside-ssh/813545#813545

Comment: @Tolsadus i edited my post, and i also tried to run traceroute, but i'm not sure wheter there is a problem there. Though the ping is working

Comment: @inaki i've already seen this post, but still not found the solution from it. you mean public and private key in my .ssh on my computer ? or on the remote server ?

Comment: Ohhh... Did you removed the public key from the .ssh folder ?

Comment: I believe you're looking for https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321968/trying-to-ssh-into-server-and-getting-key-load-public-no-such-file-or-directory as an answer.

Comment: @Tolsadus i already this one too
i generated new public key and i copy/paste mine on the remote server in .ssh/authorized_keys
but i still have this issue

Comment: @DPrat I mean the pki pair on your computer under .ssh, you indeed need to copy your public key to the remote server in order to use key based authentication over ssh, preferably using `ssh-copy <remote_user>@<remote_server>` from your pc. If the latter is done already and works without vpn this shouldn't be the cause.

Comment: @DPrat If possible it would probably help a lot to see logs from the server side (`tail -f /var/log/secure /var/log/messages /var/log/syslog`) while attempting to login.

Comment: @inaki as i said i put my public rsa key in .ssh/authorized_keys .
on the server i don't have /var/log/secure /var/log/messages and from the /var/log/syslog i'm not sure to see anything relevant...
the connection is only working with the VPN otherwise it's not working